# How to sequence authentication using Express and Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, express, google-oauth

this is a authentication sequence question. I currently have a website that is hosted with an Express back-end, which manages the routing for both my main website and the API points. For any of my routes, the request has to come with a posted OAuth token for the website, which corresponds to a specific GMail account.

I have a function which checks this token/corresponding email to be authorized to access my website (although auth function is not done, this is not the problem).

```
function validateUser(token) {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            if (!token)
                reject("Empty token");
            request(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=' + token,
                (error, response, body) => {
                    console.log(body);
                    if (error) {
                        return reject("Error");
                    } else if (JSON.parse(body)['error_description']) {
                        return reject(JSON.parse(body)['error_description']);
                    } else if (body) {
                        let theDict = JSON.parse(body);
                        theDict['oauth_token'] = token;
                        return resolve(theDict);
                    }

                    return reject("some other error");


                }
            );
        }
    );

}
```

Then I have a route that manages get requests at any location (which then redirects to the login page, and once user is logged in it posts to the  route with the token to get the content).

```
router.post(
    '/*',
    (req, res, next) => {
        var token = req.body['token'];
        validateUser(token).then(
            (data) => {
                request(
                    'http://localhost:4200',
                    (err, remoteResponse, remoteBody) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).end('Error');
                        }
                        res.send(remoteBody);
                    }
                );
            },

            (err) => {
                res.redirect('/login');
            }
        );


    }
);
```

Now, the problem here is, whenever I go to the main page of my site (which reverse proxies back to the dev server), loading the index.html file works fine, but obviously loading everything else like "/assets/js" or default Angular 2 files does not work because they are not similarly authenticated.

Is there a way in Angular 2 to send these requests using the same authentication method? I have the oauth token being stored in my Angular 2 application once the index.html is loaded, so maybe I can use that somehow?

Alternatively, I can also setup another API route in Express to load the files from there, but when Angular 2 generates my index.html with the extra script tag for loading vendor.js or other files, can I tell it this new location instead?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In express, you can use `serve-static` to serve static files, which would take precedence over your `/*` route. See https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html for more details.

Note: this assumes your static assets don't require authentication (which they usually don't).

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Note: this should be above the block declaring the `/*` route in order for it to take precendence.

If you `script.js` file lives in the `/public` folder, it will be served at the root of the express server.

Comment: Static assets do not need authentication for me no. Really do appreciate that insight, completely forgot about static delivery. However, the default Angular 2 files always load from root. Can I change this somehow or is it set in stone?

Comment: What do you mean by "always load from root"? I'm not very familiar with Angular.

Comment: It's a more angular related query, but when Angular compiles the TypeScript to javascript files, it automatically adds the script tags to index.html and the files load from "/" instead of "/assets/". I was trying to change that.

Comment: yeah that should work. I just updated the answer to add that.

Comment: Nope seems that /* still overrides static

Comment: you can probably set the path in Angular, I'm just not familiar enough with it or your setup to answer definitively. if you can provide more explanation of your setup, perhaps someone could help with that.

Comment: @ytpillai did you set the `express.static` block above your `/*` declaration?

Comment: Yup just got it all. Thanks for your help. I'm accepting your answer now